# What temp for a secondary maturation?

Tags: maturation, temperature

My first Irish Red Ale is at the secondary fermentation for about a week, I want to put the secondary fermenter to maturate on a refrigerator (with digital control for temp) for one more week before bottling.

So what is the best temp to maturate?

I used a Danstar Nottingham yeast in this beer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fridge, I'd condition it at serving temp.  But if you are not kegging the beer after, you may need to add more yeast at bottling time if you cold crash it for too long.

There may still be enough yeast in suspension when you go to bottle, but they'll be very sluggish after the cold crash.

EDIT
Re reading your post later, I think you'll be fine on the yeast issue.  If you cold crash for one week then you should be able to bottle without the need of additional yeast. So don't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to transfer this beer from secondary fermenter to another fermenter because my secondary doesn't fit on my fridge. I'm planning to condition my Irish Red Ale for about a week in 5C before bottling, so I think it's gonna be ok.

Comment: What do you mean by cold crashing?